# How to map path to path.html in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

My old site was dynamic so all the permalinks were of this form:
`http://wangling.me/2000/01/file` or ``http://wangling.me/2000/01/file/`

Now I just rebuilt my site with static html files so permalinks become:
`http://wangling.me/2000/01/file.html`

So I want to map old permalinks to new permalinks. I wrote this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wangling.me`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xxx
     ServerName wangling.me
     ServerAlias *.wangling.me
     DocumentRoot doc_root
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond /$1 !-d
     RewriteCond /$1 !-f
     RewriteCond /$1.html -f
     RewriteRule ^/([^.]+?)/*$ /$1.html
</VirtualHost>
```

But it does not work. Here are the relevant logs:

> [Sat Jan 19 00:49:01 2013] [error] [client 24.12.163.253] File does
>   not exist: doc_root/2012/05/xyz

So it seems the `RewriteRule` is not used. I know there must be something wrong with my config because I'm even not sure what exactly `Pattern` is in `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution`. Is it the absolute URL(http://wangling.me/2012/05/xyz), relative URL(2012/05/xyz), absolute file path(doc_root/2012/05/xyz), or relative file path(2012/05/xyz)?

Comment: use `RewriteLog` to troubleshoot. If your rules are alright, look at your `error_log` more closely. Perhaps something like SELinux is to blame.

Comment: Can you clarify your new document path.  Did you not rename the files .html?  If you did, then      RewriteCond /$1 !-d
 may be the issue since the directory now exists.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid You can think of it as renaming from `file` to `file.html`. Why would `/$1` exist? Isn't `$1` = `file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By try-and-error, I found that `Pattern` is relative URL(/2012/05/xyz) in `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution`. So the correct configure is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xxx
     ServerName wangling.me
     ServerAlias *.wangling.me
     DocumentRoot doc_root
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
     RewriteRule ^/([^.]+?)/*$ /$1.html
</VirtualHost>
```